# groupby() is not binning the columns and DataFrame original column gets deleted when using .allias

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark(2.x.x) using spark-sql , I created a dataframe using spark sql context.

```
dff = sqlCtx.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true").option("delimiter","\t").load("/home/hduser/Desktop/allFromDesktop/pyspark/creditData.csv")

dff.show()

Income|Limit|Rating|Cards|Age|Education|Gender|Student|Married|       Ethnicity|Balance|Age_class|
+---+------------------+-----+------+-----+---+---------+------+-------+-------+----------------+-------+---------+
|  0|14.890999999999998| 3606|   283|    2| 34|       11|  Male|     No|    Yes|       Caucasian|    333|    25-34|
|  1|           106.025| 6645|   483|    3| 82|       15|Female|    Yes|    Yes|           Asian|    903|      65+|
|  2|104.59299999999999| 7075|   514|    4| 71|       11|  Male|     No|     No|           Asian|    580|      65+|
```

i tried unit testing the code

```
tab=dff.select(['Age_class','Balance','Limit']).groupby('Age_class').agg
  (F.count('Limit')  ,F.mean('Limit').alias('Limit_avg'),F.min('Limit').alias('Limit_min'),F.max('Limit').alias('Limit_max')).withColumn('total',sum(col('Limit')).
  over(Window)).withColumn('Percent',col('Limit')*100/col('total')).drop(c
  ol('total'))
  tab.show()
```

and found that as soon as agg(),count function executes the original column gets replaced by new .allias column names 
unit test #1 (first part of the python code executed succesfully)

```
tab=dff.select(['Age_class','Balance','Limit']).groupby('Age_class').agg(F.count('Limit_count')
    ,F.mean('Limit').alias('Limit_avg'),
    F.min('Limit').alias('Limit_min'),
    F.max('Limit').alias('Limit_max'))
    tab.show()
```

With output:

```
output:
---------+------------+------------------+---------+---------+
|Age_class|count(Limit)|         Limit_avg|Limit_min|Limit_max|
+---------+------------+------------------+---------+---------+
|    45-54|          65| 4836.630769230769|      855|    11200|
|      <25|          11|3932.6363636363635|     2120|     6375|
|    55-64|          68|            4530.0|     1311|    11966|
##Here you can see i lost my original 'Limit' column ##
```

Original Dataframe which  has a column 'Limit' got deleted (why??) replaced by new column i.e i loose my original dataframe column  when *second part* of the code runs it is unable to find original column in the dataframe .
soo..
Rest of the part of the statment i.e *.withColumn('total',sum(col('Limit')).
   over(Window)).withColumn('Percent',col('Limit')*100/col('total')).drop(col('total'))*

Shows the error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2104.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Limit`' given input columns: [Age_class, Limit_max, Limit_min, Limit_avg, count(Limit)];;
```

Now when i changed my groupby clause to -->>.groupby('Age_class','Limit') insted of .groupby('Age_class') my code gets executed with desired result ** 
**QUESTION 1: Why i need to add "Limit" column to groupby() clause ?? When i alredy mentioned it in SELECT statement
QUESTION 2:After execution the "Age_class" column did not get converted to groups(bins) even though iam using "groupby"  see expected  result table below i was expecting some thing like  ??**

```
+---------+----------+------------------+----------+----------+-------+
|age_class|Limit|count(Limit)|Limit_avg|Limit_min|Limit_max|Percentage
+---------+----------+------------------+----------+----------+-------+
|
  45-54     |120|3183.0666666666666|338|12612|12.0||
  <25       |150| 2970.733333333333|276|15672|15.0||
  55-64     |56| 3493.660714285714|385|15945|5.6||
  35-44     |254| 3403.771653543307|250|15857|25.4||
  25-34     |397| 3298.823677581864|343|18424|39.7||
  65+       |23|3210.1739130434785|571|14896|2.3|
+---------+----------+------------------+----------+----------+-------+
tab=dff.select(['Age_class','Balance','Limit']).groupby('Age_class','Limit').agg(F.count('Limit')
,F.mean('Limit').alias('Limit_avg'),
F.min('Limit').alias('Limit_min'),
F.max('Limit').alias('Limit_max')).withColumn('total',sum(col('Limit')).over(Window)).withColumn('Percent',col('Limit')*100/col('total')).drop(col('total'))
tab.show()
```

Actual output('Age_class' Not converted into groups(a.k.a bins)):

```
+---------+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|Age_class|Limit|count(Limit)|Limit_avg|Limit_min|Limit_max|            Percent|
+---------+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|    45-54| 7838|           1|   7838.0|     7838|     7838| 0.4137807247233719|
|    35-44|  886|           1|    886.0|      886|      886|0.04677337612974069|
|    45-54| 4632|           1|   4632.0|     4632|     4632|  0.244530788073317|
|    55-64| 1448|           1|   1448.0|     1448|     1448|0.07644226708336853|
|    55-64| 5107|           1|   5107.0|     5107|     5107| 0.2696068080074331|
|    45-54| 2586|           1|   2586.0|     2586|     2586| 0.1365191316834192|
|    35-44| 4159|           1|   4159.0|     4159|     4159| 0.2195603513810288|
|    45-54| 4943|           1|   4943.0|     4943|     4943| 0.2609489821775488|
|    45-54| 2558|           1|   2558.0|     2558|     2558|0.13504096629782922|
|    25-34| 3969|           1|   3969.0|     3969|     3969|0.20952994340738237|
|    35-44| 5319|           1|   5319.0|     5319|     5319| 0.2807986316411859|
|    45-54| 8100|           1|   8100.0|     8100|     8100| 0.4276121294028212|
|    45-54| 6040|           1|   6040.0|     6040|     6040| 0.3188613903201284|
|    45-54| 4673|           1|   4673.0|     4673|     4673|0.24669524453078806|
|      65+| 2330|           1|   2330.0|     2330|     2330| 0.1230044767294535|
|    45-54| 6922|           1|   6922.0|     6922|     6922| 0.3654235999662134|
|      65+| 4263|           1|   4263.0|     4263|     4263|0.22505067995607736|
|    25-34| 4391|           1|   4391.0|     4391|     4391|0.23180800743306024|
|      65+| 7499|           1|   7499.0|     7499|     7499|0.39588436523355014|
|    45-54| 8732|           1|   8732.0|     8732|     8732|  0.460976433820424|
+---------+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Because you grouped by `Age_class`. Do you want to group by both?

Comment: no only Age_class.

Comment: @vikassingh: Please don't add new questions (especially not when somebody already answered, answers will get out-of-date then). In this case however the reason it's not grouping as you want is due to you grouping on two columns, `Age_class` and `Limit`. You say you want to keep the `Limit` rows after groupnig but the new dataframe (grouping by only `Age_class`) will have a different number fo rows. You need to think about which value of `Limit` would you like to keep. You already have min, max and mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @pault said, because you only grouped by `Age_class`. If you use aggregation functions, the resulted dataframe will only return the aggregated columns (i.e the targets you are trying to aggregate : `count(Limit)` `Limit_avg` `Limit_min` `Limit_max()`) and the dimension columns against which you apply aggregation functions (i.e `Age_class`).

If you want to preserve `'Limit'`, you should at least apply some aggregation function against it, for example :

```
tab=dff.select(['Age_class','Balance','Limit']) \
.groupby('Limit', 'Age_class') \
.agg(F.count('Limit_count'),
     F.mean('Limit').alias('Limit_avg'),
     F.min('Limit').alias('Limit_min'),
     F.max('Limit').alias('Limit_max'))
```

As for why you should include `'Limit'` in `groupby()`, generally speaking, you will write something like :

```
df.select(col1, col2, col3, col4) \
.groupBy(col1, col3) \
.aggregate(F.count(col1), F.sum(col3))
```

You can think what you did in this way :

For given PySpark DataFrame `df`, we select part of its columns `col1`... `col4` to get a smaller DataFrame `df.select(col1, col2, col3, col4)`.

And for this smaller DataFrame, we want to check some aggregated results against some dimensions : we want to know for the dimension we care, that is `col1` and `col3`, how many rows of the dimension `col1` (i.e `F.count(col1)`) and what is the total sum for the dimension `col3` (i.e `F.sum(col3`).

And what are those dimensions I care about? they are defined in  `.groupBy(col1, col3)`.

Comment: plz look at question 2 :After execution the "Age_class" column did not get converted to groups(bins) even though iam using "groupby" see expected result table below i was expecting some thing like ?? .........Age _class data type is string